# Proving that a limit is $0$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the proof that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x^n = 0$ is true when $|x| < 1$? Is it something assumed as true by definition or is there a way to show it?

Comment: This is proven in virtually *any* elementary real analysis textbook. Have you done any research? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't have any textbooks

Comment: This is most definitely provable, there are a ton of ways to do so.

Comment: Ok, then it's proved in hundreds of pdfs and websites scattered around the internet. I googled "limit x^n" and found [this proof](https://www.math.uh.edu/~jiwenhe/Math1432/lectures/lecture18_handout.pdf) as the very first hit.

Comment: When you're asked to prove something, assuming that something is true is **_not_** proving it.

Comment: We want to show that the limit of $|x|^n$ is $0$. Suppose $|x|\gt 0$. Let $|x|=\frac{1}{1+t}$.  Then $|x|^n =\frac{1}{(1+t)^n}\lt \frac{1}{nt}$. Now the usual $\epsilon$-$N$ is easy. This argument has appeared more than once on MSE.

Comment: @T.Bongers I did see that but it explains it in terms of other limits, which seems like circular reasoning to me because now you have to look up proof for pinching theorem and limit of $e^u$ (not circular but rather doesn't simplify)

Comment: @KG The main point of my last comment was that this is something *very* well known and posted in many places on the internet. If that proof doesn't have the background you prefer, check out the second hit or the third hit. Questions here ought to show some research and effort: Had your question been something like "I want to understand this limit. This proof I found has __insert flaw here__. Can it be proved a different way?" then it would be a much better question.

Comment: @KG Regarding your comment "I don't have any textbooks," may I offer a strong recommendation for [Elementary Real Analysis](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf) by 
Thomson, Bruckner, and Bruckner? This is a highly readable introduction, and the PDF is a free, legal download.

Comment: Does this have answers so I can check myself against those exercise problems?

Comment: @KG No, it has hints for some exercises but not most. But you can always ask questions here if you are uncertain. By the way, see pages 72-73 in that PDF, for another proof of this result.

Comment: Looks like a great book, thanks for the recommendation and link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x = 0$, the result is obvious, so assume $0 < |x| < 1$. Then by a simple induction argument we have $0 < |x|^{n+1} < |x|^n$ for any natural number $n$. Therefore the sequence $\{|x|^n\}$ is decreasing and bounded below by zero, so it converges to some limit $L$.

Now define $y_n = |x|^{n+1} = |x||x|^n$, and observe that on the one hand,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}y_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}|x|^{n+1} = L,$$
since $y_n$ is a subsequence of $\{|x|^n\}$. On the other hand,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}y_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}|x||x|^n = |x|\lim_{n \to \infty}|x|^n = |x|L$$
Consequently we have $L = |x|L$, or $L(|x| - 1) = 0$. As $|x| \neq 1$, this forces $L = 0$.

This shows that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}|x|^n = 0$$
which is equivalent to
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}x^n = 0$$

Comment: How do we know it converges to some limit $L$? How do we know we can factor out $|x|$ outside of the limit?

Comment: @KG Any monotonically decreasing sequence which is bounded below, [is convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers). (This is also true for any monotonically increasing sequence which is bounded above.) We can factor $|x|$ outside the limit because it does not depend on $n$, so it is a constant with respect to the limit operation.

Comment: Confused on that link, what is $a_n$ versus $a_N$? Is $c$ supposed to be the same as a boundary / asymptote?

Comment: @KG $N$ is a specific, fixed natural number which satisfies $a_N > c - \epsilon$. Such an $N$ is guaranteed to exist by definition of $c$ as the supremum of $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$.

Comment: So $a_N > c-\epsilon$ means "there's always an $a_N$ we can make closer and closer to $c$ but never equalling or surpassing it"? So if $n$ is even greater than $N$ is this meant to show that $c-a_N$ is squeezed between $c-a_n$ and $\epsilon$?

Comment: @KG Since $c$ is the supremum, no element of the sequence can exceed $c$, so $a_n \leq c$ for all $n$. Then for the specific $N$ mentioned above, we have $c - \epsilon < a_N \leq c$. Moreover, since $a_n$ is increasing, we have $c - \epsilon <  a_n \leq c$ for every $n \geq N$. Since we can find such an $N$ for any given $\epsilon > 0$, this means by definition that $a_n$ converges to $c$.

Comment: "It converges to $c$ because $a_n$ always increases but never becomes greater than $c$", right? What if $a_n$ _actually does_ surpass $c$ as we increase $n$? Doesn't this still fit the definition of convergence as stated? Just because we can always point out $a_N$ closer and closer to $c$ doesn't mean it converges to $c$ right?

Comment: @KG $a_n$ can't surpass $c$. We have defined $c$ to be the supremum (least upper bound) of $a_n$. By definition, any upper bound (including the least upper bound) is a number which $a_n$ never exceeds. Note that $a_n$ may or may not ever reach $c$. Convergence does not require $a_n$ to reach $c$, just that $a_n$ can be made as close to $c$ as we like, by choosing large enough $n$.

Comment: Let's say I define $a_n$ as $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...$ and I want to say it converges to $10$. Just because I define $10$ as the supremum doesn't make it so. Or is the definition of convergence saying that $c$ is the number such that this holds true (i.e. it would fail for $10$ because we can show $a_n > c$)?

Comment: @KG $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\ldots$ is not bounded above, so it does not have a (finite) supremum. A sequence has a finite supremum if and only if it is bounded above. The claim is that **if** a sequence is bounded above and is increasing, then it converges to its supremum. (And, analogously, if a sequence is bounded below and is decreasing, then it converges to its infimum.)

Comment: @KG For an example, consider $a_n = 1 - 1/n$. Then $a_n$ is bounded above by $1$ (or by any number larger than $1$). Moreover, it eventually exceeds any number smaller than $1$, so $1$ is the **least** upper bound (supremum). And indeed, $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 - 1/n = 1$.

Comment: Does "bounded" mean "there does not exist any $a_n > c$" in this case?

Comment: So then if $a_n = 1 - n$ it is bounded from above by $1$ but not bounded from below by anything?

Comment: @KG "Bounded" means "there is some $M$ such that $a_n \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$". A fundamental property of the real numbers is that if there exists such an $M$, then there exists a **smallest** such $M$, which is by definition the supremum or least upper bound of the sequence.

Comment: @KG Correct, $a_n = 1-n$ is bounded above by $1$ (indeed the supremum is $1$), but it is not bounded below.

Comment: @KG The comments are not intended for extended discussion. If you like, we can [continue this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43322/bungo)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, for $\;0<x<1\;$:

$$x^n=e^{n\log x}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

since $\;\log x<0\;$. The extension to $\;-1<x<0\;$ is easy now.

Another way:

$$|x|<1\,,\,\,x\neq0\implies x=\frac1{1+y}\;,\;\;y>-1\implies$$

$$|x|^n=\frac1{(1+y)^n}\stackrel{\text{Bernoulli Ineq.}}\le\frac1{1+ny}\le\frac1{ny}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: The $\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}$ part is not satisfying to me as it's skipping over the difficulty I am having with all these proofs. How do you know or define things "going to $0$ at $\infty$"?

Comment: That right arrow is just another way to write $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\;$ . Your  second line's question is not clear to me: you must know the definition of limit of a sequence to attack this problem, and " things going to zero at $\;\infty\;$" is not limits...

Comment: That's what I am asking about though, because every proof I see seems like it just makes a lot of assumptions. Every time I see any kind of "...and then it just goes to $0$ at infinity" I get frustrated. I want to know _why_ and _how_ we can say this with certainty.

Comment: @KG It is not "assumptions" . The limit $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0\;$ is one of the first ones, if not **the** first one, that students are *usually* introduced to right after the very definition of limit of sequence. I assume you *already* know this and the very elementary and basic limits and theorems shown in the answer above, otherwise you should have written in your question what you know or how you need to prove your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|x|<1$, it can be written as $\frac{1}{1+h}$ for some $h>0$ (case $x>0$, other case is done similarly). Now we have $$0\leq \frac{1}{(1+h)^n}\leq\frac{1}{1+nh},$$ where we used Bernouli's inequality $(1+h)^n\geq 1+nh$. Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+nh}=0,$$
by squeeze theorem we have $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^n = 0.$$

Comment: And how do you know $\frac{1}{1+nh}$ goes to $0$?

Comment: By $\epsilon$-$n$ definition: $\frac{1}{1+nh}<\frac{1}{nh}<\epsilon$ for $n>\frac{1}{h\epsilon}$.